# Algorithm Analysis: Frequencies of Execution

Tags: java, algorithms

I am currently reading the Analysis of Algorithms section in [Algorithms, 4th Edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) and I'm trying to understand how the author calculated **(N^2)/2** and **(N^3)/6** *frequencies of execution* in the code snippet below ([here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/41analysis/ThreeSum.java.html) is the full code):

```
public class ThreeSum
{
    public static int count(int[] a) {
            int N = a.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { // <---------------- 1
                for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) { // <---------- N
                    for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++) { // <------ N^2/2
                        if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0) { // <--- N^3/6
                            cnt++;  // <---------------------- x
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return cnt;
        } 
}
```

Why divide N^2 by 2? Why divide N^3 by 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a part of using "[partial sums](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/partial-sums.html)" to determine the frequencies of execution. The specific section is "Useful Shortcuts" where it shows what eventuality exists for a given starting term order in a sequence.